# How do I get the Steam library view to open on "Installed"?

Tags: steam

Whenever I fire up Steam for the first time after a reboot, the library view defaults to "All Games". My list of games is far too long for this, and every time I fire it up I switch it to "Installed" view. How can I get Steam library view to default to this?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you select the "Installed" view on the Library tab, and then exit Steam (file > exit) and restart Steam again, clicking on the Library tab will default you to the last selected view before you exited Steam (which would be the installed games view).

This only seems to work if you specifically exit the game, rather than let it close when you restart your computer.

<sup>Tested as working on Steam 1367621987 build date May 3 2013, 15:12:10</sup>

Comment: Are you sure your date is right? Might be 3 june instead of 3 may?

Comment: [Absolutely 100% certain](http://i.stack.imgur.com/1xhlv.png)...

Comment: Note that as of today, this same method will determine the default game selected.